# PostgreSQL ODBC - EnableBulkLoad parameter

Tags: postgresql, odbc, libpq, psqlodbc

Please, help, Does "EnableBulkLoad" parameter (maybe under a different name) exist for ODBC PostgreSQL driver?

Watched ODBC driver(version 11.0) from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/src/ and can't find in docs about this parameter(
Tried add it in odbc.ini like "EnableBulkLoad = 0" for PostgreSQL entry and there was't any difference.

I hope that parameter for disabling bulk load does exist because I get error  trying to insert some data "*The session failed to run because bulk mode is enabled in the DSN entry. Disable bulk mode for ODBC.*"

Comment: I can confirm that this parameter does not occur in the source of the ODBC driver. It probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks a lot) Does it mean that parameter for load type has different name? Or impossibility of changing load type for PostgreSQL at all?

Comment: What makes you think that the parameter exists? What is it supposed to do? Please add that information to the question rather than writing a comment.